# side effects of using ereg_replace and its replacement

Tags: php

I'm new to php. I have the following code:

```
$this->image["format"] = ereg_replace(".*\.(.*)$", "\\1", $imgfile);
$this->image["outputformat"] = ereg_replace(".*\.(.*)$", "\\1", $save);
```

which is working fine but I'm receiving an error Deprecated: Function ereg_replace().
I want to ask if there are any side effects of using deprecated functions in php? and if there is some other replacement. I tried preg but it's not working either. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can also pull up file extension with `$ext = array_pop(explode('.', $file_name))`

Comment: but I want to convert it to preg_replace can you please help me with the resulting code after replacement.

Comment: It may just be a matter of adding delimiters to your regular expression, everything else looks fine.  Have you tried `preg_replace('/.*\.(.*)$/', '\\1', $imgfile)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Using deprecated functions is bad practice, you -can- use them, but it is not suggested, since they are not supported anymore and might not appear in later versions of php.

Instead of your function you should use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (i take it you already tried it, but check out documentation, maybe you were doing something wrong)

EDIT to answer question in comments:

Your replacement will look like this:

```
$this->image["format"] = preg_replace("/.*\.(.*)$/", "\\1", $imgfile);
$this->image["outputformat"] = preg_replace("/.*\.(.*)$/", "\\1", $save);
```

Note that pattern starts and ends with forward slashes `/.*\.(.*)$/`

Comment: can you please show me what will the replacement after converting it to preg_replace may be I'm not doing it correctly.